# template argument deduction failed in variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm writing a function that can pour the content of a string vector into variables. Here's what it looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, int N = 0>
void pour2(std::vector<std::string> const& vals, T& val) {
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss << vals[N];
    ss >> val;
}

template <typename T, typename ...Ts, int N = 0>
void pour2(std::vector<std::string> const& vals, T& val, Ts& ...args) {
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss << vals[N];
    ss >> val;
    pour2<Ts..., N+1>(vals, args...);
}


int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> info = {"3", "1.5", "/home/tq/playground/"};

    int sz; 
    double val;
    std::string dir;

    pour2(info, sz, val, dir);

    std::cout << "size = " << sz << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value = " << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dir = " << dir << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, g++-9.2 complains that

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void pour2(const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, T&, Ts& ...) [with T = int; Ts = {double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}; int N = 0]’:
test.cpp:30:26:   required from here
test.cpp:18:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘pour2<double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, (0 + 1)>(const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, double&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’
   18 |  pour2<Ts..., N+1>(vals, args...);
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:7:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, int N> void pour2(const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, T&)’
    7 | void pour2(std::vector<std::string> const& vals, T& val) {
      |      ^~~~~
test.cpp:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:18:19: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be at least 1)
   18 |  pour2<Ts..., N+1>(vals, args...);
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:14:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class ... Ts, int N> void pour2(const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, T&, Ts& ...)’
   14 | void pour2(std::vector<std::string> const& vals, T& val, Ts& ...args) {
      |      ^~~~~
test.cpp:14:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

and clang-9.0.1 says

```
test.cpp:18:2: error: no matching function for call to 'pour2'
        pour2<Ts..., N+1>(vals, args...);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:30:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pour2<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> , 0>' requested here
        pour2(info, sz, val, dir);
        ^
test.cpp:14:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Ts'
void pour2(std::vector<std::string> const& vals, T& val, Ts& ...args) {
     ^
test.cpp:7:6: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
void pour2(std::vector<std::string> const& vals, T& val) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I find that if I move the non-type template parameter to be the first argument, the code can compile and work as expected:

```
template <int N = 0, typename T>
void pour(std::vector<std::string> const& vals, T& val) {
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss << vals[N];
    ss >> val;
}

template <int N = 0, typename T, typename ...Ts>
void pour(std::vector<std::string> const& vals, T& val, Ts& ...args) {
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss << vals[N];
    ss >> val;
    pour<N+1, Ts...>(vals, args...);
}
```

I just wonder, why it doesn't work in the first case?

Comment: I believe it's due to the fact that the variadic part of the template must be the last parameter in the template.

Answer (score 1):

If N appears after the parameter pack, N needs to be deduced from the function arguments or have default arguments, and N cannot be deduced by the functions argument.

> "In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier in the list provided that all following parameters can be deduced from the function arguments, or have default arguments". - [[parameter_pack - cppreference]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I thought passing template arguments explicitly should also work but you are right that's not the way it works.